# Font size <strong> not scaling correctly

Tags: css, firefox, font-size, bold

Using percentages for scaling font size gives unexpected result with the `<strong>`-tag. The same happens using 'font-weight' setting. If I set the paragraph to 90%, the bold part does not seem to scale down. If I set it to 80% however, it scales down correctly. This effect is most noticable in FireFox (version 50).

What settings do I need to use to get a `<strong>` that is the same size as the normal text?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <p>
        This is normal text.<br>
        <strong>This is bold text.</strong>
    </p>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body { font-family:arial,sans-serif;font-size:90%}
p { font-size:90% }
```

See also this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f7wyb13d/3/

UPDATE: This is an image of the fiddle result I'm seeing:[image: []

I noticed this problem, because I was changing font sizes from pt to %. Settings in pt did not give a difference in font-size. Perhaps it is indeed a local issue in my setup. Maybe I stick to pt then, to cancelled out possible differences depending on user's system.

Comment: The computed font size of the example you link to is 12.96 pixels for both the paragraph and the strong elements within it. I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely an illusion and some fonts will have this effect more than others.  If you aren't picking a font, then Firefox might be using one that looks more dramatic.  The characters will be wider because it is in bold, as the strokes are heavier.

But it is the same height.  Characters have an x-height, which is the height of m or n.  The example you have of the interlaced text's have the same x height:

[image]